# QToolButton and emiting signals

Tags: c++, qt

What signal is emmitted if I click on QToolButton's arrow part of a button? The clicked signal is emitted wherever I click on it but I need to detect only when the specified part is clicked on.
[image]

Comment: Button does not emit any special signals in this case, it displays associated menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to intercept menu's aboutToShow signal and connect this signal with id est, reinitialize_menu_ slot, and in this slot you can do necessary checks and adjustments.
Good luck.